# Creating a Simple Java Webserver. Image is not showing up

Tags: java, server, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm currently in (1st year) college and was assigned to do Java Server. Currently, I have created a really simple HTML page (Hello world style) and text shows up in the Localhost. However, when I insert an image into it, it doesn't show up... I get that the header should "tell" that there's an image coming to the server so it can read an image as such, but how do I do it? As you can see by my code, as last resort, I tried to pass a second header for that image, but I also get an error "SocketException". How do I, through an HTML page, pass image and text to my webserver so it shows up on my localhost?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pathImage = "www/1st.png";
        String pathHTML = "www/index.html";

        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9000);

            byte[] html = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathHTML));
            byte[] imageToBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathImage));

            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection: OK");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println(in.readLine());

                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 Document Follows \r\n" +
                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n" +
                        "Content-Length: " + html.length + "\r\n" +
                        "\r\n");

                out.write(html);
                out.flush();

                out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 Document Follows \r\n" +
                        "Content - Type: image/png > \r\n" +
                        "Content - Length: " + imageToBytes.length + "\r\n" +
                        "\r\n"); */

                out.write(imageToBytes);


                System.out.println("file has passed");
                out.flush();
                out.close();


            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how HTTP works.  Either have multipart content or separate code for each object.

Comment: You must send only a single set of headers. Study up on HTTP, starting with the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_header_fields).

Answer (score 0):

You succeeded in transferring a simple HTML page to the client. That is a good base. Add

```
<img src="..."/>
```

into the HTML and you will see that after downloading that HTML from your server the client comes back with a new connection, asking for the image to be delivered. The response on that second request must be the image only, not the HTML page.

So you need to distinguish what the client is requesting and serve the correct content.

Answer (score 0):

A socket serving HTTP waits for a single HTTP request, then provides a single response for that request.

You cannot just dump all of your responses into a single socket.  You have to examine the request you have received, then provide a response which is appropriate for that request.

The first thing you must do is examine the first line in the InputStream.  This is the greeting line, which must be in the format *method* *path* HTTP/*version*.

*method* is a standard HTTP request method (always `GET` in the case of your program).  *path* is based on the URL entered into the browser, probably `www/index.html` or `www/1st.png`.  *version* is one of `1.0`, `1.1`, or `2.0`.

So you need to parse that line before you do anything else:

```
String greeting = in.readLine();
if (greeting == null) {
    throw new IOException("Missing greeting.");
}

String[] parts = greeting.split(" ");
String requestPath = parts[1];
```

Then you can decide what to return based on that path:

```
byte[] contentToReturn;
String contentType;
if (requestPath.endsWith("1st.png")) {
    contentToReturn = imageToBytes;
    contentType = "image/png";
} else 
    contentToReturn = html;
    contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
}
```

Then you must write *only that one file* to the response:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

out.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 Document Follows\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Length: " + contentToReturn.length + "\r\n" +
        "\r\n");

out.write(contentToReturn);
out.close();
```

The browser will open a new socket (that is, an HTTP connection) for the HTML file and for each resource (such as an image) referenced in the HTML file.  You only have to be prepared to serve each one.

Some other points:

- Spaces matter.  Do not put a space at the end of any header line before the `\r\n`.
- Spaces matter in header names.  It's `Content-Type`, not `Content - Type`.  The first form is valid, the other is not.
- There is no need to flush an OutputStream before closing it.  `close()` is guaranteed to flush any remaining data.